# Racket: Lack of debug message coming from Emacs with Geiser

Tags: emacs, racket, read-eval-print-loop, geiser

I am newbie to use emacs with geiser. Currently, I do not have any problem with its regular operations, such as compiling program or launching REPL. But I do not know why the REPL within Geiser only provides very limited information if my program goes wrong.

For example, I use a mutable list but accidentally use `assoc` rather than `massoc`, the error message from REPL in Geiser is

```
install-deriv-package: undefined;
cannot reference undefined identifier
  context...:
   /Applications/Racket v6.0.1/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
```

However, in the REPL of DrRacket, the error message would be more enlightening:

```
assoc: not a proper list: (mcons (mcons 'deriv (mcons (mcons '** #<procedure:deriv-
exponential>) (mcons (mcons '* #<procedure:deriv-product>) (mcons (mcons '+ #
<procedure:deriv-sum>) '())))) '())
```

For the former case, I do not even know where the mistake is.

Is it relevant with the configuration of Geiser? If so, how can I make the error message similar to the one in DrRacket?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but your particular issue seems to be a problem with `install-deriv-package`  being undefined in your Geiser environment, but not being undefined in your DrRacket environment. In any case, it seems to me that the messages generated in the Geiser REPL, `geiser-compile-file` output, and DrRacket output are quite similar (at least in the case of using `assoc` rather than `massoc` on a mutable list):

Geiser REPL error:

```
racket@> (assoc 3 (mlist (mlist 1 2) (mlist 3 4) (mlist 5 6)))
assoc: not a proper list: (mcons (mcons 1 (mcons 2)) (mcons (mcons 3 (mcons 4)) (mcons (mcons 5 (mcons 6)))))
  context...:
   /Applications/Racket v6.5/collects/racket/private/misc.rkt:87:7
```

Geiser REPL w/out error:

```
racket@> (massoc 3 (mlist (mlist 1 2) (mlist 3 4) (mlist 5 6)))
(mcons 3 (mcons 4 '()))
```

`geiser-compile-file` error:

```
Compiling ~/development/lisp/racket/error_testing.rkt ...


Error: struct:exn:fail:contract <- THIS TEXT IS ACTUALLY LINKED TO THE GEISER DOCS PAGE

assoc: not a proper list: (mcons (mcons 1 (mcons 2)) (mcons (mcons 3 (mcons 4)) (mcons (mcons 5 (mcons 6)))))
```

`geiser-compile-file` w/out error:

```
Compiling ~/development/lisp/racket/error_testing.rkt ...


(mcons 3 (mcons 4 '()))
```

DrRacket error:

```
(assoc 3 (mlist (mlist 1 2) (mlist 3 4) (mlist 5 6)))
. . assoc: not a proper list: (mcons (mcons 1 (mcons 2 '())) (mcons (mcons 3 (mcons 4 '())) (mcons (mcons 5 (mcons 6 '())) '())))
```

DrRacket w/out error:

```
(mcons 3 (mcons 4 '()))
```

As you can see, all of these outputs seem rather similar. However, to answer your question, I think that `geiser-compile-file` is the best Geiser option to use here since it gives slightly more information about the error than the Geiser REPL output. Also, the `geiser-compile-file` buffer defaults to `geiser-debug-mode`, so that may help with debugging somewhat. Lastly, you may also want to check out [this section on the Geiser site.](http://www.nongnu.org/geiser/geiser_4.html#To-err-perchance-to-debug)